# Date selector not allowing today's date as accepting

Tags: javascript, function, date, if-statement

This code only allows future events.

The problem I am having is that it will not allow today's date to be submitted, but I need it to be allowed. How can I accomplish this?

Here's my code:

```
if ( this.element.find( '#visitdate' ).length > 0 ) {
  var dateParts = $( '#visitdate' ).val().split( '/' );
  var check = new Date( dateParts[2], dateParts[1]-1, dateParts[0], 0, 0, 0, 0 ).getTime();
  var today = Date.now();
  if ( today > check ) {
    _errMsg = "Please enter a future visit date";
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Uh, midnight of "today" is never a future event…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem that I see in your sample code is that your are taking Date.now(), which includes hours, minutes, secods, etc

You could better do something like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var today = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
```

Then you can check difference in times:

```
if (today.getTime() > check ) {

}
```

**UPDATE: Example code**

```
if (this.element.find('#visitdate').length > 0) {
  var dateParts = $('#visitdate').val().split('/');
  var check = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1]-1, dateParts[0], 0,0,0,0);
  var d = new Date();
  var today = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
  if (today.getTime() > check.getTime() ) {
    _errMsg = "Please enter a future visit date";
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to give me that example within my code sample so i understand? @edrian

Comment: @JPS I have included an example within your example code

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use days as the resolution for your dates, not the precise time. After changing this, your code would look like this:

```
if ( this.element.find( '#visitdate' ).length > 0 ) {
  var dateParts = $( '#visitdate' ).val().split( '/' );
  var check = new Date( dateParts[2], dateParts[1]-1, dateParts[0] ).getTime();
  var today = new Date( Date.now().getFullYear(), Date.now().getMonth(), Date.now().getDate() ).getTime();
  if ( today > check ) {
    _errMsg = "Please enter a future visit date";
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: @JPS Could you please explain how that would impact the validity of this solution?

Comment: excuse me if i am wrong but getTime is a timed in mini-seconds from the date January 1970 to whatever date is selected. This means every mini-second the number will change so it will never be equal. Does that make sense? @APerson

Comment: @JPS I'm reasonably certain that `getTime()` returns a number, which can be compared with the number you get from [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

Comment: Yeah but it is constantly different so how would you compare a number which could be different every second? @APerson